# How to keep footer in one place?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an animation that keeps pushing the footer down with each `@keyframes`

My footer html:

```
<div class="footer 
callout"></div><footer 
id="colophon" class="site- 
footer footer bg-dark" × 
role="contentinfo">
<div class="container footer
inner"><div class="row"><div 
class="footer-widget-area">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm- 
6 footer-widget"
role="complementary">
<div id="text-4" 
class="widget widget_text">. 
<div class="textwidget"><p>. 
<a href="http://4309.co.uk/
contact/">Contact</a></p>
</div>
```

Animation html:

```
<div class="fptext">some 
text some text some 
text</div>

<div class="fatext">some 
text some text some 
text</div>
```

Css

```
@media(max-width: 768px). 
{.fatext{animation: bigger 
50s ease forwards;animation. 
delay: 0s;; 
position:relative;font-size: 
15px; color:#43ff0a;bottom: 
1700px; font- 
weight:bolder;padding: 
0px;background. 
color:blue;display:block;}} 

@keyframes bigger 
{from{font-size: 0px} to 
{font-size: 18px;}}
```

And:

```
@media (max-width: 768px). 
{.fptext {animation: fadeout 
50s ease forwards;animation. 
delay: 0s;
}}

@keyframes fadeout{
from {font-size: 0px} to. 
{font-size: 40px;}}
```

As I understand the element needs to be positioned relatively for the animation to work, so I can't re-position it. I could re-position the footer though, which I tried.

```
.site-footer{position: 
absolute;}
```

Didn't work.

```
.site-footer {position: 
fixed;}
```

Didn't work.

```
.site-footer 
{position:static;}
```

Didn't work.

The only other solution, not really viable, is that I animate the footer to go back up the page once the animation is finished. That is set a 40s delay on it and then animate it back from topx px to top x px. I'd rather just have it not move at all though. That may however give me a gigantic footer unless I can control height. Alternatively, can padding or negative/relative padding be used?

Working example [here](https://4309.co.uk) on mobile

In addition, I've discovered that using margin-bottom does work but simply increases the gap between the footer and the bottom of the page whilst maintaining the gap between animation and footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using `position:relative` with `bottom` and negative `margin-bottom` and holding footer at `position:static`

```
@media(max-width: 768px){.fatext{animation: bigger 50s 
ease forwards;animation-delay: 0s;; position:relative;font- 
size: 15px; color:#43ff0a;bottom: 1700px; font- 
weight:bolder;padding: 0px;background. 
color:blue;display:block;margin-bottom: -1750px
}}
```

And:

```
@media(max-width: 768px){.site-footer{background. 
color:black; height: 150px;z-index:100; 
position:static;margin-top:0px} 



}
```